# PHP random number in email

Tags: php, html, wordpress, email

I have a Wordpress website where i am making a form so that when a user fills out that form he gets a confirmation email and receives a unique order number. I have this PHP function which creates that number any suggestions is it possible to embed it to an email with a shortcode. Maybe could someone can put me on the right track.
Thank you in advance.

```
function genTicketString() {
    $length = 8;
    $characters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)];
    }
    return $string;
}
add_shortcode('quoteticket', 'genTicketString');
?>
```

Comment: This code generates a *random* string, not a *unique* one.

Comment: @Merijn, I usually use uniqid(), do you recommend against this function in favor of your method?

Comment: @sam good thing you said that. will delete my comment. you'er totally right on that! thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldn't run this in the email, but you could before it is sent and print the result in the html to be sent. html email doesn't allow anything other than html and css, so anything dynamic (no js either) must be done pre-send or in a web page hyperlinked from the email.

Answer (score 4):

replace mt_rand with [uniqid](https://www.php.net/uniqid)
To embed the result of a shortcode in an email I recommend asking at wordpress stack exchange